# Realm Query - RealmResults<SuperclassType>

Tags: realm

Quite new to Realm, but off the bat I like it.

With that said, since progging in Java, I'm using inheritance/polymorphism extensively.

Does anyone know if Realm supports querying for saved data by using a superclass type that extends realm object?

eg:
final RealmResults result = iRealm.where(SuperclassType.class).findAll();

Thanks Kindly

Comment: `I'm using inheritance/polymorphism extensively.` -- considering inheritance of classes that aren't specifically `RealmObject` is not supported by RealmObjects, you'll need a different mindset for designing a Realm schema. You can for example *"store all concrete types"* (you can share interfaces tho), **or** *"store all types in one obj. using a discriminator column."* You cannot directly store an object hierarchy..

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported right now. You can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761 for that. Until then you need to use composition over inheritance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance